# Repository Pattern: How to track the entity state while updating/deleting based on filter?

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository-pattern, crud, unit-of-work

I'm implementing the Repository pattern (over Mongo DB) together with the Unit of Work.
Adding/updating/deleting entities from the repository simply updates an in-memory (tracking) list of the entity's state, which is then used by the Unit of Work in its `SaveChanges()` method to actually perform the CUD operation on the database.

For example the `Repository.Add()` method:

```
public void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    TrackingList[entity] = new EntityData<TEntity>(entity, EntityState.Added);
}
```

Then, in the Unit of Work `SaveChanges()` implementation:

```
var addedEntities = repository.TrackingList.Values.Where(v => v.State == EntityState.Added).Select(v => v.Entity);
if (!addedEntities.Any())
    return;

// inserts the added entities to the Mongo DB collection
repository.Collection.InsertMany(addedEntities);
```

This works when explicitly performing CUD operation on specific entities. Then I can manage this tracking list.
But now I'm trying to implement the following method:

```
DeleteWhere(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> filter);
```

The problem is that I can't track the changed entities since I don't know anything about the entities that will pass the filter.

I may also have to support partial entity updating by filter.

What is the right way to do this, if possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the ORM that implements *bulk delete (conditional or not)* and *bulk update (conditional or not)* features by **fully honoring** UoW. Yes; many ORMs support these features; but in that case, UoW is not honored or partially honored. Yes, the database action will be only executed on flushing (`SaveChanges()` as you said); but in-memory copy or in-memory state will not guaranteed to be in a consistent state with underlying RDBMS.

There is a reason for this being so. For UoW to work, entity must be loaded in memory. With the cases above, this is not guaranteed. Only way to make these two features work under UoW is to **load those entities in memory in background** (if not already loaded) and then take the action. This will be very inefficient. Many ORMs provide these two features by not honoring or partially-honoring the UoW.

About *partial entity update*, you have to track changes in *properties* (member level) instead of just tracking change in entity (class level).

In my knowledge, there are two ways to track the changes:

1. Flag

   You just maintain some flag against each instance of an entity in memory. If any action is taken on that particular instance, you modify its related flag accordingly. While flushing, you only check this flag and take the CUD action as per its state. You cannot track the changes on member level with this way.
2. Snapshot

   With this way, ORM maintains the copy of entity when it was originally loaded. Actual loaded entity is exposed for changes. While flushing, actual entity is checked against original copy. With this way, you can detect the changes on member level. Memory and other overall management cost is higher here.